# Use PHP to start/restart process

Tags: php, shell, process, ssh

I've created a php script that allows me to click a button to restart a PHP script. However, I'm not sure the best way to do it. Here's a snapshot of it: http://i51.tinypic.com/2niz32o.png

I currently have this:

```
if(isset($_POST['login_restart']))
{
    $command = exec("/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/login_server.php >/dev/null &");
    $pid = exec("nohup $command > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!");
    $info = "Login server started...PID: $pid";
}
```

However, that doesn't seem to work. I need it so when the "Restart" button is pressed, it starts the login server, and keeps it running. I've been using the screen function in SSH, however, I don't want to have to keep logging into SSH to restart the login server. I want to somehow use a process ID so I can check to see if the script is running, and if it's not, it'll allow me to click the "Restart" button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a particular reason that you want to do this manually and not automatically? Is it not the case that the server should always be restarted?

My advice would be to automate this, either by using `cron` to check the status of your script at regular intervals, or `bash` infinite loop script immortality.

First create a launcher script to invoke your PHP for convenience, and call it `run_login_server.sh` (don't forget to chmod +x it so it can be executed):

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html_login_server.php > /dev/null
```

Then create `login_server_daemon.sh` to run your script in an infinite loop (again, `chmod +x` it to make it executable):

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
  ./run_login_server.sh # or any command line to be executed forever
done
```

N.B. I have not backgrounded the php process in the above `bash` script. It works, because the bash loop will call php each time, and the loop will only iterate again once php has died. Just execute `login_server_daemon.sh` to start the loop (either through an init service or in a detached screen session like you are using now).

**If your PHP scripts hang, or you want to reload them because you have updated your code**, you can simply kill the looped process–`run_login_server.sh` and the bash loop will respawn it.

It's as simple as `killall run_login_server.sh`, which you could do via php's `exec`. *Note that you need to be careful about the user permissions of who has executed what*: if you execute `login_server_daemon.sh` as your_username but php runs as php_username then php will not have permission to `killall` your process.

Finally, if you can't choose between `cron` and the `script` approaches, here are some factors to consider:

The script should live forever, and will only die if 1) explicitly killed, 2) bash somehow trips and dies on a while loop, which I doubt would happen, and 3) a machine-wide catastrophe happens, in which case your little bash script stopping is the least of your worries. A bonus with the script is that restart is immediate after php (or whatever you want to call in the infinite loop) dies.

`cron` has a the problem that it can only check once a minute at its most frequent setting, if you really care about immediate recovery. It has the additional annoyance that if you decide to stop the script, you also have to remove it from your crontab or it will just come back to life.

Comment: The reason being is because the script hangs and freezes at times, and I make numerous changes to the script on a daily basis (adding game items, etc). I just find it easier to click a button to restart the process when needed.

Comment: Got it. In that case, consider combining approaches: run the immortality bash script for restarting your servers when they die, and create a script to kill them whenever you want to update or they hang.

Comment: The thing about this is I need to give access to a few other people (without giving them SSH access), so I would prefer a form so they could simply click the "restart" button, and it restarts the script.

Comment: Edited my answer to make it clear how you can restart at will by killing the action kept alive by the looping script via PHP's `exec`. I made your php command into a bash script to give it a distinctive name easily targeted by `killall`

Comment: Ok, I tried what you said, using `exec`: `exec("killall /var/www/html/run_login_server.sh");`, however, the script still isn't starting...

Comment: Ok, just to be clear, because I use this trick all the time and can vouch for it, you need to (1) execute the `login_server_daemon.sh` while loop script, which will ensure `run_login_server.sh`–invoking your php script–is run and then (2) kill run_login_server.sh whenever you want it to respawn.

Comment: Ok, I executed the login_server_deamon.sh via the screen method, however, it's saying "Permission Denied" when doing so.

Comment: You need to set run_login_server.sh to executable with `chmod` probably. Please go to chat to discuss this.

Comment: Hmm, `exec("killall /var/www/html/run_login_server.sh");` doesn't seem to be killing the script, because I made a change to the code, and executed the killall thing, but the new code doesn't work.

Comment: `killall` takes the script name, not its path. That is, run `killall run_login_server.sh`.

Comment: This is very peculiar. I replaced the killall command with the one you suggested, however, the script still isn't restarting.

Comment: You had it working before, right? Did you kill login_server_daemon.sh by accident? Did you not detach your screen session that executed it, and so when you logged out the looping script died?

Comment: Well, I guess it's not completely working. When I go and click the "restart" button, nothing happens. I tried attaching the screen session as well, but no luck.

Comment: Ok, so the script keeps running, and when you do it on the command line it works? But the restart button does not? What user does your php run as? The problem is probably that you are running `run_login_server.sh` as you, but php is another user, so `killall run_login_server.sh` executed by php is not allowed to kill it. You need to start `login_server_daemon.sh` as the php user (`sudo -u php_user login_server_daemon.sh`) so that `run_login_server.sh` is itself run with that ownership so it can be killed. P.S. We should delete all these comments once this works, and I will edit the answer.

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly do you mean by "php user"? I have to use something other than root?

Comment: Your php script (specifically, the one that responds to your restart buttons) runs on your server as a particular user. For instance, if you use mod_php with Apache it probably runs as `apache` or `www-data`. If you are starting `login_server_daemon.sh` as root, your php script will not have permission to `killall` root's process. Moral of the story, figure out your php user id and run `login_server_daemon.sh` as that user by calling it with `sudo`. If you need more than this suggestion, you might want to open a new question about PHP, users, and permissions.