# Start a daemon with php

Tags: php, linux, daemon

I want to be able to stop/start a daemon (on Debian) by clicking a button on a website. I know the daemon works, because via SSH it does start and stop. I can even capture the status with

```
$status = exec("/etc/init.d/MyService.sh status | grep 'is running'");
```

But this doesn't work:

```
exec('/etc/init.d/MyService.sh start', $output);
```

There I get this error: Starting system MyService daemon: failed! I guess it has to do with permissions but I don't know how. The permissions of the .pid file is -rwxrw-rw-

I read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6720364/3486924 and this [Starting a daemon from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8387077/3486924) but both didn't help either.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: -rwxrw-rw- means only the owner can execute the file.. are you sure php is running as the owning user? You could do a `chmod +x` and try again

Comment: When using fcgi, just change the script's owner to the one you want the service to run.

Comment: Changed it to -rwxr-xr-x now. Still no success.

Answer (score 1):

This is not certain, but a good guess would be that your php runs under a a different user than your ssh one. The one you use on ssh has some rights, the one under which php is running has others.

You can:

1. Change your php user to be the same with the ssh one
2. Change your file permissions to something like 777 (if security is not an issue)
3. exec('sudo /etc/init.d/MyService.sh start', $output); - if you have sudo
4. Change your file owner (chown)

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but how can I find out what the php user is? Is it the one under which Apache runs?

Comment: Is it possible that the permissions issue resides with the PID file? I have tried all (chmod +x, chown) on the script file in etc/init.d/, but not on the PID file as it doesn't persist.

Comment: It is possible the process call something else and gets stuck there... Try changing the php user, if this doesn't work then at least you know the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: changed the user in /etc/apache2/envvars now to the same user I run the script via SSH - still no success

Answer (score 1):

You could use [immortal](https://immortal.run) a supervisor that allows you to [manage a process via HTTP](https://immortal.run/post/nginx/) either locally or remotely by using Nginx to expose the "control" Unix-socket. You could stop/start the process,  send custom signals besides querying the current status and get the reply in JSON.

For example, this is a [`run.yml`](https://immortal.run/post/run.yml/) used to start the command `sleep`:

```
cmd: sleep 30
log: /var/log/sleep.log
```

If [immortaldir](https://immortal.run/post/immortaldir/) is used to start services on boot time, it will create the "control" socket here:

```
/var/run/immortal/sleep/immortal.sock
```

Therefore you could configure [Nginx](https://immortal.run/post/nginx/) like this:

```
upstream immortal {
    server unix:/var/run/immortal/sleep/immortal.sock;
}

server {
listen 80 default_server;
server_name _;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://immortal/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;  
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

You may need to change permission to the socket:

```
chmod 766 /var/run/immortal/sleep/immortal.sock
```

Then via your browser, you could stop:

```
http://<domain>/signal/stop
```

Or start your process:

```
http://<domain>/signal/start
```

Further steps would be to [secure the URL](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html) since everyone with access to the web server could stop/start your processes